# Objective-C pointer address

Tags: objective-c

I am very new ObjectiveC programmer ,

How do i got the value of the pointer;

```
NSString *success= [jsonData objectForKey:@"Success"];
```

This success variable give me a some memory address but i need the value of this memory address.

Thank you

Comment: `unsigned long addr = (unsigned long)success;` -- i.e., the variable is the address since the variable is a pointer to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need it for what? A `NSString` (as every object in Objective-C) is not meant to be dereferenced. Then it's not clear if you need the value of the pointer (eg. the address value) of the value of the pointed value (so basically what you obtain with `*` operator in C)

If you need to get the value of the string as a boolean you should consider

```
NSString *success= [jsonData objectForKey:@"Success"];
bool value = [success boolValue];
```

that will automatically turn the string into a boolean value (if applicable).

Comment: this JSONParse "Success" return me true or false from the server , so i need if else condition. How do i compare it with true false ...

Comment: As I wrote, use `if ([success boolValue])`

Comment: if(value==true)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                    
                } else {
                    
                    NSLog(@"Login Fail");
                }

Comment: If it worked for you, you should accept Jack's answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.